# Status code 403, not fixable with user agent header

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to extract name and price of a list of materials from a website using Python. I'm using the code below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

urls = ['https://www.bricomart.es/materiales-de-construccion/elementos-de-construccion/ladrillos-y-bloques/']

for url in urls:
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    for response in soup.find_all('div', class_='products-list-product'):
        Price = response.p.text
        print(Price)
```

I'm using headers because, without it, it gave me a 403 error. Now I don't get the error (status code is 200), but still can't get the information I need. I get nothing when running this code.

Can someone please help? I'd prefer to stick with Beautifulsoup and requests, as my understanding of coding is pretty limited.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data are coming from ajax request so you can call it like that:

```py
import requests

url = "https://www.bricomart.es/rest/V1/products/list/%7B%22page_size%22:20,%22filters%22:%7B%7D,%22order_by%22:%7B%22field%22:%22order%22,%22dir%22:%22ASC%22%7D,%22retailer_id%22:%2272%22,%22category_id%22:%22materiales-de-construccion%252Felementos-de-construccion%252Fladrillos-y-bloques%22,%22page_id%22:1%7D"
headers={
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0",
    "Referer": "https://www.bricomart.es/materiales-de-construccion/elementos-de-construccion/ladrillos-y-bloques/",
    "Authorization": "Bearer lhzi2b9ks5fryccceiby6b1u34v4fe6i",
    "Cookie": "vuex=%7B%22cookies%22%3A%7B%22user%22%3A%7B%22token%22%3A%22%22%2C%22rememberMe%22%3Afalse%2C%22sessionStarted%22%3A%22%22%2C%22isUserPro%22%3Afalse%2C%22allowedSaveCookie%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22selectedStore%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%2272%22%2C%22seller_code%22%3A%22030%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Bricomart%20Galdakao%22%7D%2C%22isEcommerceActivated%22%3Afalse%7D%7D; datadome=AZTOTNH91rT1ZGLmtYO0SayhnzsesiJ-R3p.5mw8SWra1mJGOy7ugg9rF9Pyqt~aXVdnr5VOsir2WqwgNF-nQmNDUMAnXifm-U0ejpeHyt; _gcl_au=1.1.578284498.1626128324; PHPSESSID=uuukea8g85essiht6nqu0pot3m; t2s-analytics=46bc4ebc-4220-4124-9543-f5f12e4e996a; t2s-p=46bc4ebc-4220-4124-9543-f5f12e4e996a; _ga=GA1.2.802881557.1626128326; _gid=GA1.2.2126596679.1626128326; %40%40=1"
}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
products = r.json()[0]["list"]

for p in products:
    print(p["name"], '||', p["price"], '€')
```

Output:

```sh
LADRILLO MEGABRICK 70.5X51.5X7 CM TABIQUE || 1.45 €
LADRILLO RUSTICO ROJO 22.5X11X4CM || 0.27 €
LADRILLO LISO CLINKER BILBAO ROJO 23.6X11.4X5CM || 0.31 €
RASILLÓN MACHIHEMBRADO 100X30X4 CM || 0.97 €
ALBARDILLA CREMA 19X25X6 CM || 0.86 €
LADRILLO MEGATOSCO 30X19X12 CM || 0.39 €
LADRILLO TABIQUERO HUECO DOBLE 33X15X7 CM || 0.18 €
LADRILLO REFRACTARIO 22X11X4 CM || 0.72 €
LADRILLO PERFORADO 24X11,5X10CM || 0.15 €
BLOQUE DE HORMIGÓN LISO CREMA 39X19X14 CM || 1.09 €
BLOQUE DE HORMIGÓN LISO CREMA 39X19X19 CM || 1.32 €
BLOQUE DE HORMIGÓN GRIS 39X19X14 CM || 0.64 €
BLOQUE DE HORMIGÓN GRIS 39X19X19 CM || 0.68 €
BLOQUE LADRILLO TERMOBRICK 30X19X24 CM || 0.79 €
BLOQUE LADRILLO TERMOBRICK 30X19X19 CM || 0.62 €
BLOQUE LADRILLO TERMOBRICK 30X19X14 CM || 0.48 €
BLOQUE DE HORMIGÓN SPLIT MEDIO CREMA 19X19X19 CM || 0.93 €
BLOQUE DE HORMIGÓN SPLIT ESQUINA CREMA 39X19X19 CM || 1.93 €
BLOQUE DE HORMIGÓN LISO MEDIO CREMA 19X19X19 CM || 0.83 €
BLOQUE DE HORMIGÓN LISO 4 CARAS CREMA 39X19X19 CM || 1.48 €
```

Comment: thanks so much! This is exactly what I needed!!

Comment: thank you again for your solution. I have a follow-up question though. I noticed the output does not match what is shown on the website. Sometimes the products and prices are different. Do you know why this happens? Also, could you please point me to where I can learn more about this method? I'd like to know how you came up with these headers, for example. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It will not be working because your website is loading dynamically. It means that after opening the page, the website tries to get information about materials and prices from the backend, from the server. When you tried to use the requests library, you get a page before loading from the server. You need to use a system that can simulate a user on the website.

If you want to solve this problem, you need to use the Selenium library. This library imitates user that wants to visit the site. Your bot on Selenium can wait until the page will be loaded and after that parse it.

- Selenium documentation: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/
- Example of using Selenium in python: https://www.browserstack.com/guide/python-selenium-to-run-web-automation-test

**EDIT**

For example, if we want to connect to the website using simulation of a Google Chrome browser, we need to use that code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('path_to_chromedriver')
driver.get("your_website")
```

After that, we need to wait for when the page will be loaded. We can use a special timer:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(seconds)
```

or write a code, until what moment we need to wait:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'someid')))
```

Last one - we need to find an required element:

```
driver.find_element_by_name("your_element")
```

After working with the code, you need to close your Chromedriver using:

```
driver.close()
```

Those are the main tips that can help you. Good luck!

Comment: thanks so much for the detailed explanation! I'm not familiar with Selenium, but can probably make it work thanks to your instructions. Thanks